# Create and Update Dictionary Key Value Pair using PNP js

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, pnp-js-core, pnpjs

I have a doubt in Key-value pair object. I need to create a key value pair and then I need to update it.

Example: I have to create the following kind of object:

```
var itemval = {
   Id:1{Name:aa,Idval:1},
   Id:2{Name:bb,Idval:2},
   Id:3{Name:cc,Idval:3},
   Id:4{Name:dd,Idval:4}
}
```

During update I need to check the Id. If Id matches then add item in that section.

Below example Id is 1 so we are adding value in it.

```
var itemval = {
   {Id:1{Name:aa,Idval:1},{Name:ee,Idval:5}}, 
   Id:2{Name:bb,Idval:2},
   Id:3{Name:cc,Idval:3},
   Id:4{Name:dd,Idval:4}
}
```

This value I need to store it in SharePoint list column as JSON object using pnp.js.

Can someone assist me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your sample object.
You could use for...in to get all object key an value.

```
for (var key in itemval){
    console.log(key +':'+ itemval[key])
}
```

Pnp js add new  item:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("My List").items.add({
  Title: "Title",
  Description: "Description"
});
```

You could get official demo here:https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#add-items